# Why not work " forever stop forever/development.json "?

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js, forever

I install forever npm package using follow command

```
sudo npm install forever -g
npm install forever-monitor
```

My server.js file run using follow command

```
forever start server.js
```

Result :

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: server.js
```

Now server.js running background

Next server.js file stop using follow command

```
forever start server.js
```

Result :

```
info:    Forever stopped process:
    uid  command         script    forever pid  id logfile                       uptime       
[0] uiip /usr/bin/nodejs server.js 5763    5765    /home/amila/.forever/uiip.log 0:0:1:38.529
```

Finally reading documentation, I added development.json inside forever directory

```
{
"uid": "app",
"append": true,
"watch": true,
"script": "server.js",
"sourceDir": "./"
```

}

Now Type :

```
forever start forever/development.json
```

Result :

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: server.js
```

Now server.js file working.

Problem here : Type follow command

```
forever stop forever/development.json
```

Result :

```
error:   Forever cannot find process with id: forever/development.json
```

However when type

```
forever stop server.js
```

Result :

```
info:    Forever stopped process:
    uid command         script    forever pid  id logfile                      uptime       
[0] app /usr/bin/nodejs server.js 6437    6443    /home/amila/.forever/app.log 0:0:1:44.323
```

I need now, Why when type `forever stop forever/development.json` comes error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the forever process does not start properly, then it will automatically be stopped.

So stopping a process, which is already stopped due to an error, then forever will throw an error for that

```
error:   Forever cannot find process with id: forever/development.json
```

Is development.json file contains below line?

```
{  "script" : "server.js"  }
```

Update:

Valid Parameters

**`forever stop Id|Uid|Pid|Index|Script`**

Comment: Have you checked with node server.js is it starting properly without any error

Comment: `forever start forever/development.json` When type command. node server is run properly. There is no error.

Comment: stop doesnot allow from json script you can use forever stop Id|Uid|Pid|Index|Script

Comment: forever stop **Id|Uid|Pid|Index|Script**